# how to repopulating a dropdown in codeigniter after form validation fails?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<select style="width:25%;" name='state' <?php if(form_error('state') != '') {  echo 'id=error'; } ?>>
<option value=''>State</option>
 <?php  foreach($states->result() as $row)
 {
 echo "<option value='$row->state_name'>". $row->state_name."</option>";
 }  ?>
</select>
```

hi, i am facing problem in the above code, please help me,
set_value is not working for me, dropdown is not populating after form validation fails , thanks in advance
 or

does something like this works, here target is hidden value. now how to set target value to drop down value(option value)

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function (){
    target=document.getElementById('target').value;
        if(target.length!=''){
   // document.getElementByName('state').value=target;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You may need to re-execute the query on form validation fail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the manual:

```
<select name="myselect">
        <option value="one" <?php echo  set_select('myselect', 'one', TRUE); ?> >One</option>
        <option value="two" <?php echo  set_select('myselect', 'two'); ?> >Two</option>
        <option value="three" <?php echo  set_select('myselect', 'three'); ?> >Three</option>
</select>
```

#### In your case

```
<select style="width:25%;" name='state' <?php if(form_error('state') != '') {  echo 'id=error'; } ?>>
<option value=''>State</option>
 <?php  foreach($states->result() as $row)
 {
 echo "<option value='$row->state_name' " . set_select('state', $row->state_name) . " >". $row->state_name."</option>";
 }  ?>

</select>
```

[UPDATE]

```
<select style="width:25%;" name='state' <?php if(form_error('state') != '') {  echo 'id=error'; } ?>>
    <option value=''>State</option>
     <?php  
$defaultvalue = 'Nigeria'; //Please set default value here when nothing is selected before submit - change Nigeria
foreach($states->result() as $row)
     {
     echo "<option value='$row->state_name' " . set_select('state', $row->state_name, ((!isset(set_select('state', $row->state_name)) &&  ($row->state_name == $defaultvalue) ) ? TRUE : FALSE )) . " >". $row->state_name."</option>";
     }  ?>


</select>
```

Just remove TRUE from set_select if you don't want to set a default value

If you use a  menu, this function permits you to display the menu item that was selected. The first parameter must contain the name of the select menu, the second parameter must contain the value of each item, and the third (optional) parameter lets you set an item as the default (use boolean TRUE/FALSE).

Comment: You can't add the `TRUE` flag in the loop, or it'll try to specify every option as the default.

Comment: dosent work dude. Last value in the dropdown is getting selected always.@jornsen

Comment: I've seen why. I just updated my answer. You could take out the TRUE flag (3rd parameter) or use the 2nd example if you want to set default value. Sorry I can't test because I don't have enough info, but this should do the trick or give your a good head start.

Answer (score 4):

If you use form helper function, you can do the following.

`form_dropdown('name', $options, set_value('name', 'default'))`

`set_value` will select the option value if post with 'name' was submitted last time. If not, it will set it with 'default' value.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the post value?

```
echo form_dropdown('name', $options, $this->input->post('name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [set_select()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html), not `set_value()`. Unless your form validation isn't firing at all..

```
<select style="width:25%;" name='state' <?php if(form_error('state') != '') {  echo 'id=error'; } ?>>
<option value=''>State</option>
 <?php  foreach($states->result() as $row)
 {
 echo '<option value="$row->state_name" ' . set_select('state', $row->state_name) . '>'. $row->state_name."</option>";
 }  ?>
</select>
```

Let me know if that's still not working, and it's perhaps something to do with the Form Validation not firing (unless `id="error"` is showing).

Comment: can we use javascript, by taking hidden input types and setting the hidden value to selected value

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select style="width:25%;" name='state' <?php if(form_error('state') != '') {  echo 'id=error'; } ?>>
    <option value=''>State</option>
     <?php  foreach($states->result() as $row)
     {
     echo "<option value='$row->state_name' " . set_select('state', $row->state_name) . " >". $row->state_name."</option>";
     }  ?>

    </select>
```

This worked for me. Thanks for the answer @jornsen.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a better way for populating select value after a form validation run FALSE In Codeigniter. Here is the CODE Snippet.

Following is my Controller.

```
function index() {
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}

function form_validation() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'trim|callback_check_if_gender_selected');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->index();
    } else {
        $this->load->view('validation_passed');
    }
}

function check_if_gender_selected($value) {
    if ($value == "0") {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_if_gender_selected', 'Please Select Gender');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

My Views

1. Form View     -(Note: I tried to paste my code but there was a problem with pasting, So here I am Proving a picture of my code. click on Image to see code better.)

[image: Form View Code]

Validation Passed View

```
Welcome Validation Passed.

<?php echo "<br />" . "Name Value = " . set_value('name') . "<br />"; ?>
<?php echo "Gender Value = " . set_value('gender'); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <option value="<?= $row->state_name ?>" ><?= $row->state_name ?></option>
```