# codeigniter set_value not working only for select controls that are populated by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I was having a problem where after a failed attempt to submit a form, the data was no longer displayed on the page.

In reading this post [CodeIgniter's set_value() not re-populating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393477/codeigniters-set-value-not-re-populating) I learned about the set_value() method in CI.

So I added it to all my fields on my form, and its working except for 2 select boxes that are created statically, but populated via ajax.

Here's what the static HTML looks like in part:  ( you can assume that I have the form and table tags)

```
<tr><td colspan="3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control"  name="widget_num" id="widget_num"  value="<?php echo set_value('widget_num'); ?>">
       </select>
     </div>
 </td></tr>

 <tr><td colspan="3">
     <div class="form-group">
         <select class="form-control" placeholder="Site:" name="site" id="site"  value="<?php echo set_value('site');?>">
         </select>
    </div>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3"><input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Location" name="location" value="<?php echo set_value('location');?>"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3"><input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Department" name="department"  value="<?php echo set_value('department');?>"/></td></tr>
```

Unlike the answer in the post I've referenced here, although I have the form libraries loaded, I'm actually not using the CI validator. 
In other words, in the controller method, instead of having something like this:

```
public function assign()
    {            
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('widget_num', 'DID', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('site', 'DID', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
```

I'm just validating everything via jquery before I allow the submit event to happen.

I do load the following in my constructor:

```
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
```

I don't really want to use the CI form validation "stuff" if I can avoid it. 
I think it's related to the fact that  doesn't use value? 
I'm googling right now but haven't found answer.  But I'm guessing that's the issue...
I found this post [how to repopulating a dropdown in codeigniter after form validation fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368561/how-to-repopulating-a-dropdown-in-codeigniter-after-form-validation-fails) but I don't quite understand how / if I can apply the answers there to my question.

Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly urge you to use the CI validation. It is server side. Jquery only tells you if something is empty or not. CI validation is much more applicable and powerful if you use it correctly. Jquery does not add any form of security like CI validation can when used right

Comment: @Brad thanks for the suggestion.  I will consider that for the production version.  right now i'm just building prototype and have to finish in short order.  But good comments about security.  thank you